# Can't install USB 3 drivers on Windows 7 (Pro)

Tags: windows-7, usb-3

I have recently downgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 7 on my Laptop. I know it has 2 USB 3.0 ports (the blue sockets). I'm currently using the "Intel 7 Series C216" chipset .

The problem is, I tried installing the "Intel USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller" driver, and it wouldn't let me. Opening setup.exe would give the "this system does not meet the minimum requirements..." message. I also tried manually updating the usb host controller by directing it to the inf files through Device Manager. However, it says it's incompatible and the device wouldn't start.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I use an ASUS K55A laptop with i7 3630QM. The Chipset is Intel HM76.

EDIT 2:

Link to setupapi.dev.log:
https://www.box.com/s/64jb6podzbjzxtq794yg

EDIT 3:

I have 2 USB 3.0 and 1 USB 2.0 sockets. Could the USB 2.0 controller be interfering with the USB 3.0?

EDIT 4:

This is what my Device Manager looks like 
[image]

Comment: try the driver 1.​0.​8.​251 from here: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=Intel%20USB%203.0%20eXtensible%20Host%20Controller%20Driver. Also post which laptop you use.

Comment: I did try that version.

I use an ASUS K55A laptop with i7 3630QM. The Chipset is Intel HM76.

Comment: have you tried the driver from ASUS? http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K55A/#support_Download_30 If this also fails, upload the file "C:\Windows\Inf\setupapi.dev.log"

Comment: Yes, I have also tried that one.

Comment: upload the log file.

Comment: Uploaded, it's at https://www.box.com/s/64jb6podzbjzxtq794yg

Comment: Windows installs the driver, but it fails to start (CM_PROB_FAILED_START). What this code means is explained here: http://pete.akeo.ie/2011/03/troubleshooting-usb-device-development.html. Do you have the Sp1 installed? Maybe the Intel driver needs it.

Comment: Yes, this is Windows 7 Professional with SP1.

Comment: call the ASUS support. On my Dell laptop (HM77) I was able to install the USB 3.0 drivers under Win7.

Comment: As a follow up to this:
Apparently, I had disabled some USB related option (Legacy Support I believe) in BIOS.
Now that I have re-enabled it, USB 3.0 is back on my laptop.
Sorry for the troubles.

Comment: ok, nice to hear this :)